# Rounding Measurement to Foot instead of 12 in

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro that is taking the difference of two integers and printing it on another sheet. Instead of saying 1ft - 12in I want it to say 2ft - 0in. Below is the code I have been working on.  ExistingCom and NewCom are the two measurements between subtracted. The Round function rounds the measurement to the nears tenth. So 19.33 would be 19.3. The full sentence that is being produced is as follows - "Lower attachment by 2ft-0in to a height of 18ft-3in".Thanks!!

```
Private Sub LowerCom(MakeReadyData, Index, ExistingCom, NewCom)

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Lower attachment by " & _
     Int(MakeReadyData(Index, ExistingCom) - MakeReadyData(Index, NewCom)) & _
     "ft-" & Round(((MakeReadyData(Index, ExistingCom) - MakeReadyData(Index, NewCom)) _
      - Int(MakeReadyData(Index, ExistingCom) - MakeReadyData(Index, NewCom))) * 12, 0) & _
     "in to a height of " & Int(MakeReadyData(Index, NewCom)) & "ft-" & _
      Round(((MakeReadyData(Index, NewCom)) - (Int(MakeReadyData(Index, NewCom)))) * 12, 0) & "in."
      Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6)).Merge

End Sub



                    If myarray(i, CatvNew) < myarray(i, CatvExist) Then

                    Call LowerCom(myarray, i, CatvExist, CatvNew)
                    XX = "*POLE CLEARANCE FROM " & myarray(i, 3)

                Else

                    Call RaiseCom(myarray, i, CatvExist, CatvNew)
                    XX = "*GROUND CLEARANCE"

                End If
            End If
```

Comment: kindly edit this question for more clarity.

Comment: Please share how you are calling `LowerCom`.

Comment: Convert all values to inches, sum, then divide by 12, this gives number of feet. Then take the remainder as a decimal expression of inches - convert to inches as needed.

Comment: We still don't know what `myarray`, `CatvNew` and `CatvExist` are. But I think you have a good [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515082/rounding-measurement-to-foot-instead-of-12-in?noredirect=1#comment105202111_59515082) already.

Comment: Hi John, welcome to StackOverflow. I presume your input fields are decimal feet? You need to break that equation down for clarity for yourself and us. Declare a couple of variables for Existing and New and operate on those. To convert decimal feet to get the inches your need something like Inches = (Feet * 12) MOD 12 . Use the MOD function to get the remainder

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this.

Could be done in straight Excel with formulas.

The trick is to:

1. convert everything to the lowest common denominator, (inches in your case. Could be date and times too. Same concept applies).
2. Then subtract inches from each other.
3. Then convert back to feet and inches.

You only need to know about Excel `MOD` and `INT` along with some rudimentary maths.

VBA ref for these operands:

- [MOD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator)
- [INT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions)

The only other thing you might consider is the `ABS` operator so you always get a positive result.

`D4 = ABS(D2-D3)`

See this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pNGL6CABj6f39_35roqoZHNImN1OZtTW-eAk3B7SNXU/edit?usp=sharing)

**Formulas:**
[image: Formulas]

**Data:**
[image: Data]